# UILabel gets hidden behind UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have made a subclass for `UITableViewCell` and I am implementing Subtitle `TableViewCell` with a thumbnail image. 
Following are the `UITableViewCell` contents:
[image: TableViewCell]

The issue I am facing is when the data loads in TableViewCell, the subtitleLabel text gets hidden upto the height of the imageView. But when I select any Cell, it shows subtitleLabelText completely.

I have added the screenshot of the same for complete reference:
[image: Subtitle text for the user 'andi242' gets hidden]

---

The `UIImageView` has frame = CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);

Comment: `[yourTableViewCell bringSubViewToFront: yourLabel];`

Comment: Try to add some background colors to Labels and imgView and display. Will see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was using `TableViewCell` style as *subtitle* instead of *custom*. The style settings in `subtitle` was making the other labels to hide below them. What a silly miss!

Answer (score 2):

Try to give a clearColor background color for the cell title label -

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Try to give a background color other than white to the title, see if it takes the exact frame that hides your subtitle, also I'd suggest to give the subtitle a background color, it's easy to spot layout problems.

Answer (score 0):

In your nib or storyboard file, make sure that the label is below the image view in the list of subview components (it is in the left of the screen). The first subview in that list will be at the lowest level (behind every other subview, if they overlap).

Answer (score 0):

write one line of code

```
 Titlelabel.backgroundcolor = [UIColor ClearColor];
```

because your label has white background..and Titlelabel height is too large so label is colliding.

Let me know working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: I set the titleLabel's background color to nonclear/nonwhite but the problem still persists. And the titleLabel is not overlapping with subtitleLabel that I have checked.

Answer (score 0):

What is the frame of Title Label? if its height is more, then also it may possible that it hides your subtitle Label

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great tutorial which helped me when I was trying to do something like you want :

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/

You can adapt the size of the different components (ImageView, TitleLabel, Subtitle,...)